# Installing Magento via Platform.sh on Ubuntu Desktop. Receiving error

Tags: magento2

Using Ubuntu Desktop, I installed LAMP, installed Composer, installed PHP moduled, installed Platform.sh, downloaded the MySQL DB from Platform.sh into a local DB called Magento, pulled the platform.sh project did a build, and this is where I'm stuck at.

The error reads:

```
janderson@jUbuntu:~/01$ platform build
Building application testm2 (runtime type: php:7.0)
Found a composer.json file; installing dependencies
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  Nothing to install or update
  Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.
  Generating optimized autoload files
      Skipped installation of bin bin/grumphp for package phpro/grumphp: file not found in package
  ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
  ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Running post-build hooks
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Starting build.  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Verbosity level is not set  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Starting build. (magento/ece-tools version: 2002.0.6, magento/magento2-base version: 2.2.2)  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Reconciling installed modules with shared config.  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Shared config file is missing module section. Updating with all installed modules.  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Command: php bin/magento module:enable --all  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Status: 255  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] INFO: Output: array (
  0 => 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\Framework\\Config\\CacheInterface in /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50',
  1 => 'Stack trace:',
  2 => '#0 /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create(\'Magento\\\\Framewo...\')',
  3 => '#1 /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get(\'Magento\\\\Framewo...\')',
  4 => '#2 /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, \'Magento\\\\Framewo...\', NULL, \'cache\', \'Magento\\\\Framewo...\')',
  5 => '#3 /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime(\'Magento\\\\Framewo...\', Array, Array)',
  6 => '#4 /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/f in /home/janderson/01/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50',
)  
[2017-12-26 19:47:58] CRITICAL: Command php bin/magento module:enable --all returned code 255  


  [RuntimeException]                                            
  Command php bin/magento module:enable --all returned code 255  


build

The hook failed with the exit code: 255

Build complete for application testm2
Web root: /home/janderson/01/_www

Cleaning up.
```

Any idea how to fix this?